# Convert js function with regex to python one

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I got a basic function written in js that takes some substring and matches via regex variations of the substring stored in array.

```
const arr = ['autoencoder', 'auto-encoder', 'auto encoder', 'auto', 'one'];
const arr2 = ['autoencoder', 'one'];

const fn = (s, a) => a.includes(s.replace(/\W/g, ''));

console.log(fn('autoencoder', arr)); 
console.log(fn('auto encoder', arr));
console.log(fn('auto-encoder', arr)); 

console.log(fn('autoencoder', arr2)); 
console.log(fn('auto encoder', arr2)); 
console.log(fn('auto-encoder', arr2));
```

The problem is that I cannot reproduce it in Python

```
I tried to reproduce it in this way:  

import re
a = ['autoencoder', 'auto-encoder', 'auto encoder', 'auto', 'one']
b = 'autoencoder'

def t(w, a):
  return [s for s in a if re.match(r'\W\ g', w)]

print(t('autoencoder',a))
```

But obviously I did not succeed as basically it returns empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript function does the following

```
const fn = (s, a) => a.includes(s.replace(/\W/g, ''));
```

- Replace all non word characters with empty string `s.replace(/\W/g, '')`
- Then `a.includes` determines whether the array(`a` in this case) includes this value, returning `true` or `false`

To replicate this in python you can do the following

```
>>> import re
>>> def fn(s, a):
...     return re.sub(r'\W', '', s) in a # re.sub(r'\W', '', s) replace all non word characters with empty string
```

Comment: a = ['auto-encoder', 'auto encoder', 'auto', 'one']
b = ['autoencoder', 'one']


def fn(s, a):
    return re.sub(r'\W', '', s) in a

print(fn('autoencoder', a))  In such a case the python code will return False, while js will return True

Comment: @Ison I am getting `False` in both cases. Would you please make sure that the array(`a`) is `['auto-encoder', 'auto encoder', 'auto', 'one']` in both python and Javascript

Comment: Hmm, you're right, my fault. Oh God, I was so happy finally dealing with regex to be able match different forms of some string, but no -_-